# Filesystem: Where would I place a program that makes a new project?

Tags: python, linux, filesystems

So I have written a small generator to make some of my work easier. I produce HTML banners and am asked to make between fifteen and thirty-five at a time. Instead of going through like an idiot and copy-pasting and modifying them all one-by-one, I just abstracted out the unique elements and made a generator to make them in Python. This has increased production by roughly a factor of ten, so I'm pretty happy with it.

Up to now, it's been under active improvement while I used it, but it's more or less mature at this point and I'd like to take it one step further by ceasing the current pattern of copying the latest client folder to make the next one and just write a script that will make a new folder for me from an unchanging template. Maybe write in something to convert older clients to the new templates or something. Whatever.

I'm not sure where in the Linux filesystem this should go, though. /usr/local/bin looks like it's just for binaries, and /usr/local/lib has important things like Python in it. /usr/local/src is a likely candidate, but I figured it would be best to check first, since this won't get moved once it's in.

Which of these (or other location) would be best to place something like this in?

Many thanks

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is usually used for *executables*, not only *binaries*, meaning it is just fine for an (executable) python script...

Comment: For my own home grown scripts - I have a /home/tony/bin directory which is listed in my $PATH environment variable. in the /home/tony/bin directory i have symbolic links out to the main scripts for each of my executable scripts. For each application I write I have a separate directory in my /home/tony/Development path. I only create links into /home/tony/bin once the testing is ccomplete. There is only me that runs these scripts though, so i don't need a solution which is "globally" accessible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you set up your little project in a way that it uses setuptools console scripts. Thus you can either install it into a virtualenv, or even the distributions python distro, and get an "executable" (actually just a shell-script with a shebang)

A sample setup.py looks like this:

```
import sys
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import os


setup(
    name = "santas-little-helper",
    version = "version",
    author = "Me",
    author_email = "Me@my.com",
    description = "Something descriptiv",
    packages=["toplevelpackage"],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts" : [
            "santas-little-helper = toplevelpackage:main",
            ],
        },
)
```

Comment: Interesting. What would be the benefits to doing this?

Comment: The advantage is that you get a nice even distributable package with an entry-point in a common binary location, but sources and assets tucked away where they belong in some library folder. So in the end it's of course not functionally better than any other executable script, but using a common pattern that is also used by a lot of other python packages e.g. nose is a benefit IMHO.

Comment: Oh. OK. So what you're saying is that I should put this file in /usr/local/bin and the actual scripts in /usr/local/lib?

Comment: Yepp, that would be the result if you used your system's python. But if you used a virtualenv, it would end up in there. So in the end, you don't need to care, but let the machinery work it out for you this way. You can also use "python setup.py develop" to not really install the scripts in the libs, but instead just link to them (the bin/script won't be affected) which gives you the command, but at the same time you can edit the source and immediately the effects will be visible on the next run.

Comment: Thank you. That should be a big help!